# merge two query into one single query in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my file there is already one query name `query1` and I write another query name `query2`. The o/p of both query is `userid`. Now I want to find the common `userid` from these two queries. So is there any function for that?

The `array_intersect()` function generates an error.

Comment: look this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63506/merge-two-select-queries-with-different-where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

Use a JOIN

```
$query1 = "SELECT userid FROM table1";
$query2 = "SELECT userid FROM table2 WHERE something = 10";
$joinQuery = "
    SELECT a.userid
    FROM ($query1) AS a
    JOIN ($query2) AS b
    ON a.userid = b.userid";
```

Comment: In my both query there is an array of userid.SO for that this query will work? or i have to put for-loop for that?

Comment: If you have an array of results, I `array_intersect()` should have worked. You should post your code and we may be able to help you with why it doesn't.

Comment: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" this error will show when i try to load the page